# Carousel view does not return anything

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm implementing a carrousel in my project, but the way I'm implementing it is not returning me anything, to some error in my code? Am I forgetting any options? Reference Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView is already attached

OBS: I am developing crossplataform

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
         <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Hanselman.Portable.Views.PodcastPage" Title="{Binding Title}"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"
         Icon="{Binding Icon}"  IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}"
         xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView">

<AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <cv:CarouselView x:Name="car" HeightRequest="200">
            <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Image Aspect="AspectFit" Source="{Binding imgs}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </cv:CarouselView>
          </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage>
```

---

```
 public class Dados
    {
        public string imgs { get; set; }
    }

    public PodcastPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<Dados> lista = new List<Dados>();

        lista.Add(new Dados
        {
            imgs = "car1.png",
        });

        lista.Add(new Dados
        {
            imgs = "car2.png",
        });

        lista.Add(new Dados
        {
            imgs = "car3.png",
        });

        car.ItemsSource = lista;
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried to use the images without any carousel?

Comment: Yes it works, only when I put the carousel that it disappears

Comment: I'm following this link--->      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9umPuctTn-M

Comment: Check out this one: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/66100/image-binding-using-path-in-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

```
    <cv:CarouselView x:Name="MainCarouselView" HeightRequest="100">
            <cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="jose" FontSize="50" TextColor="Black"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </cv:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </cv:CarouselView>
```

I tried without image only with the label inside and showing me my name, even so it does not return anything to me, but when I remove the carousel it works, seeing that I verified that my error is in my carousel, it is not an image question